# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mariadb, mysql-error-1064

```
INSERT INTO `items` (`name`, `label`, `limit`, `rare`, `can_remove`) VALUES ('coke', 'Coca Leaves', 20, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO `items` (`name`, `label`, `limit`, `rare`, `can_remove`) VALUES ('coke_pooch', 'Bagged Cocaine', 10, 0, 1);
```

but i find this sql error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near 'I' at line 1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code, the full content of the program execution (like the "mysql" client) or a screenshot of the program you are using where you execute this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape `name` and `limit`, because these look to be the reserved words.

```
INSERT INTO items (`name`, label, `limit`, rare, can_remove) VALUES ('coke', 'Coca Leaves', 20, 0, 1); INSERT INTO items (`name`, label, `limit`, rare, can_remove) VALUES ('coke_pooch', 'Bagged Cocaine', 10, 0, 1);
```

This one works for me.